# SQL: trying to insert large string into varchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to do an

```
INSERT INTO MYTBL
VALUES (CAST(SPACE(7997) + 'abcd' as nvarchar(max))
```

and it does not go over 8000 bytes
not sure what it is i am doing wrong

MYTBL only has one column (Col1 (nvarchar(max))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on your code you are missing last ")"

modify your code to this:

```
INSERT INTO MYTBL
VALUES (CAST(SPACE(7997) + 'abcd' as nvarchar(max)))
```

additionaly just like @datagod said you need to convert/cast your strings as `NVARCHAR(max)` before concatenation.

you can use this

```
INSERT INTO MYTBL
    VALUES ( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SPACE(7997)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 'abcd') )
```

Comment: this worked ok; still it feels kind of strange that these actions would be required in order to do such a simple insert

Comment: It's not strange, and it's not a requirement to "do such a simple insert." It’s required in order to change how the `+`operation works. If you concatenate a `varchar(7997)` and a `varchar(4)` in T-SQL, you *always* get a `varchar(8000)` with truncation. This is how the language is typed. If you want all 8001 characters of the concatenated strings, you need to add a `varchar(max)` to another string. You have to change what types are being concatenated. You only need to cast one of the strings to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, because `+` returns a long string type if either operand is a long type.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting each of your strings as nvarchar(max) first, then concatenate them.  I have found that string functions such as replicate() return regular varchar results which get truncated after 8000 chars.

Answer (score 1):

The string you are casting is `SPACE(7997) + 'abcd'`. This string is a `varchar(8000)` value of [7997 spaces]`abc`.

The concatenation is evaluated before the `CAST` operation is applied. `CAST` will change the type of the *result* of the concatenation, but surrounding the concatenation expression with `CAST` won't magically change how the `+` operation is evaluated.

SQL is a strongly typed language, and every expression must have a well-defined type that depends on the types of the operands, not on the values of the operands, and not on how the expression is used in a larger context.

The type of `SPACE(7997) + 'abcd'` is the result type of [`varchar(7997) + varchar(4)`], which is `varchar(8000)`, and truncation takes place.

Here's an analogous situation.

```
-- The `SELECT` fails, because the product of 2 and an `INT`has type `INT`
-- When `@i = 2000000000`, there is overflow.
declare @i int;
set @i = 2000000000;
select 2*@i;

-- The following also fails, for exactly the same reason, even though `BIGINT`
-- could hold the result.
declare @i int;
set @i = 2000000000;
select CAST(2*@i AS BIGINT);

-- This, however, succeeds, because now the type of the product is `BIGINT` 
declare @i int;
set @i = 2000000000;
select CAST(2 AS BIGINT)*@i;
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Would you mind marking this as an answer to your question?